# No CLR Version v4. is loaded into the target process. - CLR Profiler Error

Tags: .net-4.0, clrprofiler

I am trying to profile my application using CLR Profiler. I downloaded latest version of profiler from http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=16273. I tried to profile application by attaching a it. But always I am getting a message like this.

[image]

I tried the clrver command to identify the CLR version and it is returning v4.0.30319. How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same issue but in the following context: I was running a x86 application on a x64 system and I was trying to attach the x64 CLR Profiler to the x86 application.

As soon as I attached to the process using the x86 CLR profiler it worked fine.

Comment: Let me try that, I think I am having the same context. I am trying to run x64 profiler on x86 process.

Comment: It got resolved. Thank you. Only issue I found is I need to recompile the source.